# Google Apps Engine app.yaml file not correct? "This webpage has a redirect loop"

Tags: google-app-engine, redirect, app.yaml

I'm getting an error "This webpage has a redirect loop" when loading my Google Apps Engine url: http://my-application-id.appspot.com (my real application ID in the url of course)

Google Apps Engine requires an app.yaml file in the root of the application directory to work correctly.  Here are the contents of my file....

```
application: my-application-id
version: 1
runtime: php
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: install.php
```

Is my app.yaml file setup correctly?  The install.php file for my application works much the same way as a wordpress install.php file.  You access it from a web browser and go through the basic setup.  If my app.yaml file is correct, why am I still getting the "This webpage has a redirect loop" error displayed in my browser?

Also tried other browsers, clearing cookies, etc.  The application installation screen loads perfectly in my SDK but not live on Google Apps Engine.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  There were 2 problems.

On app.yaml, in my case, the last line needed to say "index.php" instead of "install.php"  Second, in my case, my configuration.ini file had port "80" set for MYSQL when in fact it needed to be "3306"